# C# port of libgcrypt?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'd like to encrypt/decrypt/verify/sign files in a C# application, while keeping binary compatibility with libgcrypt. (So I can, for example, encrypt a file using libgcrypt, then decrypt it in my C# application.)

Does anyone know of a C# port of libgcrypt, or a working wrapper library?

Comment: Any reason not to use something more .NET-esque? .NET has built-in cryptography, then there exist both free (BouncyCastle) and extensive commercial (our SecureBlackbox) libraries.

Comment: It's a requirement in this case to use libgcrypt, if at all possible :/

Comment: It can't be a requirement to use libgcrypt because libgcrypt is a C library. Don't be nonsensical.

Comment: Okay maybe far-fetched but definitely not nonsense.  A wrapper or a port is perfectly possible.

Comment: @notfed: fair enough, I withdraw my public objection while secretly still harboring doubts...